# Type Error: get() takes at least 2 arguments, 1 given

Tags: python, get, tkinter, arguments

I am trying to create a statement which checks whether a TextBox is empty, if that is not the case and the TextBox is not empty, then I want the textBox to refresh itself.

I have tried the following:

```
if (len(self.txtBox.get() != 0)): 
        self.txtBox.update()
        print "Textbox was not empty"
```

However I am given the following error, 'Type Error: get() takes at least 2 arguments, 1 given '. I know the error indicates that I should pass an argument in the get function, however I have seen code snippets using the get() function without passing any arguments, and either way I do not know what argument I should pass.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Besides that, you have the `()`s wrong: you don't want to check `get()`'s result for emptiness, but `len()`'s result.

Comment: Ah yes my mistake, same error involving the get() though

Comment: check if your `self.txtBox` is really a `TextBox` instance?

Comment: @user2675041 That's why I wrote "Besides": once you have solved the problem (and it seems you have), you'd have ran into the next one which I spotted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This old message](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2005-February/035669.html) from the `python-tutor` list might help. The two parameters are bizarre (to my mind: I am not a `Tk` expert) pointers, similar to string slicing but with the "pointers" being decimal numbers where the integer portion specifies the line and the decimal places specify the character numbers.

Comment: The index isn't a decimal number. It's a string of the form _line.column_. It may sometimes look like a decimal number, but it is not a decimal number. For example, the decimal numbers 1.1 and 1.10 represent the same value, but the index "1.1" and "1.10" do not represent the same character.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I am sure that will help avoid error.

Answer (score 3):

There is no widget called a "TextBox", so I don't know if you're talking about an Entry widget or a Text widget. The `get` method of the entry widget can be called without parameters, but the `get` method of the text widget requires two parameters. The two parameters are the starting and ending points of a region.

To get everything in a text widget, you should do it like this:

```
self.txtBox.get("1.0", "end-1c")
```

The `"1.0"` represents the first character, and `"end-1c"` represents the last character ("end") minus one character ("-1c") which will ignore the trailing newline that is always added by tkinter itself.

Comment: Good answer. And, of course, the pointers *can* be extremely complex as your `"end-1c"` example reminds us.